# No me sale el color en html css

Tags: html, css

Tengo el siguiente fragmento de codigo. Quisiera cambiarle el color al `<title>`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">

<title>Mi primer CSS</title>

<style>

h1{

    color: red;
}
</style>
```

Comment: ¿Ya intentaste borrando el cache del navegador?

Comment: ¿Con **CTRL + F5**?

Comment: ¿Podrías indicarnos como estás utilizando dichas clases y como las importas al HTML?

Comment: Ctrl + Shift + Supr para borrar los datos  de navegación.

Comment: Hola, lo puse mal, ya lo edité

Comment: No puedes cambiar el color al `<title>`. Esa etiqueta es para el texto que aparece en la pestaña del navegador, no se le pueden aplicar estilos

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Si lo que tenes en tu `CSS` es un `H1`

eso cambiara el color a todos los `h1` que tengas en tu `html` , lo que tenes acá es un TITLE por lo que así no te funcionara , si lo pruebas así si debería funcionar

```
<h1>Mi primer CSS</h1>
```

Answer (score 2):

Te hace falta estructurar un poquito mas el codigo, lo que quieras ver debe quedar dentro del body y dentro de este un h1
Te debe quedar asi:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Mi primer CSS</title>
<style>
h1{
    color: red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>TEXTO CON COLOR ROJO</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

También puedes cambiar el color "red" por un valor hexadecimal #FF0000
Recuerda que se compone por RGB y cuenta con valores de 0 a F, siendo F el valor mas significativo y  son 2 valores por cada color FF0000 indica rojo=FF verde=00 y azul=00.

Espero te sea útil.

Answer (score 1):

No te aparece ningún texto debido a que no tienes nada insertado en el . Deberías añadir una etiqueta como `<h1>Texto a mostrar</h1>` y así este texto se podría en rojo. 
La etiqueta `<title>` debe ser incluida en el  debido a que se refiere al título de la página html.

Answer (score 0):

Primeramente, ningún elemento dentro del elemento  pueden ser modificados, esto es debido a que son elementos de cabecera que proporcionan más que nada información sobre el archivo, te recomiendo ver el Curso de Fundamentos de Ingeniería de Software de Platzi para que entiendas más a fondo la estructura de un archivo, sobretodo el de un archivo HTML.

Ahora, resulta que tienes una etiqueta style donde pretendes agregar un color rojo a un elemento  usando css, esto es totalmente posible siempre que el elemento exista, y como en ningún momento creas el elemento , no podrás visualizarlo como es lógico.

Bien, ahora, para que esto ocurra debes de crear un cuerpo a la página, ya que la cabecera es solo para proporcionar información del archivo, para eso harías lo siguiente:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Mi primer CSS</title>
  <meta charsert='utf-8'>
  <style>
    h1 {
      color: red;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Mi Primer CSS</h1>

</body>

</html>
```

Como puedes ver acá inserté algunas lineas, la primera es el DOCTYPE muy necesario hoy en día para trabajar con HTML5 que es el standar actuar del HTML. Luego agregué el cuerpo con la etiqueta body tal como te comenté, y dentro agregué el título usando la etiqueta h1.